# How do I replace certain PHP values with my own text?

Tags: php, arrays, string, wordpress, replace

Here is my PHP code:

```
$order_data = array(
    'shipping_method' => $order->get_shippingmethod(),
);
```

The **'shipping_method'** value is currently exporting the following three values:

- *'Free Shipping'*
- *'FedEx_GROUND'*
- *'UPS Next Day Air'*

I'd like to replace this text with my own of my choosing. What do I have to add to the code above to replace the text to something else? So if **'shipping_method'** = *'FedEx GROUND'*, I'd like to replace the text with just *'FedEx'*. So the three values would translate to the following:

- *'Free Shipping'* = *'Free'*
- *'FedEx_GROUND'* = *'FedEx'*
- *'UPS Next Day Air'* = *'UPS'*

I don't really have any PHP skills to speak of, just enough to build WordPress templates and tweak others code. I'm editing this code to export WooCommerce orders to a CSV file, but I need the **'shipping_method'** text to be replaceable with the text of my choice.

Please don't laugh at my embarrassing attempt at replacing the text with my PHP code:

```
$order_data = array(
    'shipping_method' => $order->get_shipping_method(str_replace('Free Shipping', 'Free', $str))
);
```

This obviously doesn't work, any help would be greatly appreciated!

The plugin I'm using is **Order / Customer CSV Exporter** by **WooThemes**:
http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-customer-order-csv-export-developer-documentation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Verbose Way:

You're close...But I'd simplify a bit and forego the `str_replace()`. I'd do something like the following:

```
$shipping_method = $order->get_shipping_method();

if ( $shipping_method === 'Free Shipping' ) {
    $shipping_method = 'Free';
} elseif ( $shipping_method === 'FedEx_GROUND' ) {
    $shipping_method = 'FedEx';
} elseif ( $shipping_method === 'UPS Next Day Air' ) {
    $shipping_method = 'UPS';
}

$order_data = array(
    'shipping_method' => $shipping_method,
);
```

However, there's no guarantee changing the shipping method value won't break other things that are dependent on it...

### One-Liner Alternative:

You could also simplify this further with [preg_split()](http://php.net/preg_split) (assuming the delimeter is always a space or underscore). This completely eliminates the need for the above `if/elseif` conditional:

```
$order_data = array(
    'shipping_method' => preg_split('/[\ _]/', $order->get_shipping_method())[0],
);
```

Comment: This was the _exact_ solution I was looking for. Nice and simple. The shipping method doesn't have anything dependent on it, so no worry about breaking things. You seriously just saved me so much time. I can't begin to thank you enough. I love this site and people like yourself! Thanks!

Comment: @MattBeckman, also added an alternative answer that does it all in one line. No ugly `if/elseif` statements needed.